# Escaping pipe in perl

Tags: perl, ksh

I'm having some trouble with backtics and pipe in perl. I have following code:

```
my @arr_lsdev = `lsdev -C | grep inet | awk '{print \$1}'` ;
print Dumper @arr_lsdev ;
```

But I get following error:

```
sh[2]: 0403-057 Syntax error : `|' is not expected
```

I'm guessing it has something to with my escape commands. I have tried escaping the | but it still results in the same error.

OS: AIX

Shell: KSH

Comment: Why use the pipes at all? Read in all of lsdev -C and use perl's own text processing abilities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that the error is on line 2. You are actually executing

```
my @arr_lsdev = `lsdev -C | grep inet
 | awk '{print \$1}'` ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the number of pipes:

```
my @arr_lsdev = map {(split ' ')[0]} grep {/inet/} `lsdev -C`;
```